# Should I be getting the "Red Dot" on the "Review Queues " Icon?

Tags: bug, review, notifications

This has happened twice now - I get the "red dot" on the "Review Queues" icon, but when I click on it the queues that are available to me (my rep is about 750) are all empty, though there are some greyed-out queues that have as many as 200 items. Am I getting notified by mistake?

---

Edit: To be clear, this isn't any big problem for me, but as the event queues are new to me (I guess I passed some reputation cut-off) I've been spending a few moments trying to figure out what/if I'm missing.

Comment: I get it as well for close votes despite not having 3k rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is not literally by mistake, but it will likely be changed. See [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302093/please-dont-red-alert-me-for-queues-ive-handled) for not the exact same matter but something related (it's about users that at the moment cannot review), where it says that several improvements are planned.

Comment: Seeing that it's a known issue and that I'm not just misunderstanding the queue system is what I wanted. Thanks.