# Redundant "Red Dot" within the review queues menu

Tags: bug, review, notifications

It happens to be that yesterday evening, for the first time since I have access to the review queues, there appeared a - I would call it - "Red Dot Icon" within the drop-down menu.

In fact this notifications seemed to be pointless since there were no review tasks to accomplish as you can see within the included picture.

[image]
First of all in order to clear up my confusion about the "Red Dot Icon" I searched here on the Meta page and stumbled upon these two posts:

- [Should I be getting the "Red Dot" on the "Review Queues " Icon?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27360/should-i-be-getting-the-red-dot-on-the-review-queues-icon)
- [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302093/please-dont-red-alert-me-for-queues-ive-handled)

Both dealing with the topic of redundant notifications for queues which they in fact *cannot* access in contrast to my case. Therefore I am little bit confused right now.

It has to be added that the notification in the first place appeared since there were about $7$ new "Suggested Edits" which were neither approved nor rejected. After completing these review tasks the "Red Dot Icon" did not vanished.

> Could someone explain to me what exactly is the reason for this strange behavior of the review queues? Is this a simple known bug or just a slight error which occured yesterday due for example the server refreshing of the review queues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the "close vote" review queue was up over 200 at the time you took the screenshot.  The Red Dot is an indicator that some review queue exceeds a threshold, site and queue dependent as I understand it.  It does seem a bit glitchy that the Red Dot is displayed for you but the "close vote" queue is not accessible.

Comment: @hardmath close/reopen vote needs 3000 rep though, so it's working by design.

Comment: That said, yes, [it's a known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798/241919).