# Bug in first questions review queue

Tags: bug, review

From my understanding, the first posts review queue shows a red dot if it is above 10 or so posts. However, it is currently displaying a red dot and clicking on it yields no questions to be reviewed:
[image]

This may not be too important, but I decided to bring it up anyway as it may inconvenience a few users.

Update: After a few minutes three posts showed up in the queue, but that still does not account for the red dot.

Comment: Is it possible that this is the same issue as reported in some previous posts? Such as "[Should I be getting the "Red Dot" on the "Review Queues " Icon?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27360)" on this meta. Or on [meta.se]: [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302093) and [Please don't show the red dot indicator for review items I can't do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798).